# Converting a audio file into a spectrogram then saving the data of the spectrogram into a txt file

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, spectrogram, saving-data

Im doing a CNN to reconize birds sounds, i know how to get the image of the spectrogram from a wav audio and save it, but ploting 46k images is taking too long, someone told me to save the data of the spectrogram into a txt file, and it can train the AI the same way, i made some search but couldn't find any way to do this, if you guys have any suggestion i would appreciate too.

heres the code:

```
def get_spectrogram(wav):
    D = librosa.stft(wav, n_fft=1080, hop_length=160,win_length=1080, window='hamming')
    spect, phase = librosa.magphase(D)
    return spect

for roots, directories,files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".wav"):
            wav, sr = librosa.load(filename, sr=None)
            ipd.Audio(wav, rate=sr)
            log_spect = np.log(get_spectrogram(wav))
            plt.tick_params(top='off', bottom='off', left='off', right='off', labelleft='off', labelbottom='off')
            ax = plt.axes()
            ax.set_axis_off()
            plt.imshow(log_spect, aspect='auto', origin='hight')
            plot_name = f"{filename[:-4]}.png"
            plt.savefig(outputdir + "/" + plot_name, dpi=1000, bbox_inches='tight', transparent=True)
```

Comment: I'm not well versed in this, but after a cursory glance at their [documentation](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/index.html) it seems like [decompose](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.decompose.decompose.html#librosa.decompose.decompose) may be helpful.